shower valve out too far from wall
I’m redoing my shower and ordered a modern Delta shower tub/faucet/cartage. The shower faucet knob fits the old shower cartridge (great) butttt the old knob is about 2.5 inches out from the wall too far. I don’t have access to the water main so I was hoping to put up cement board, tile, and put the old knob back until I can get a plumber approved (I live in a co-op). So my question is this: can I retile and leave a 4X4 hole and do this later OR would a plumber need access to the entire wall? Obviously it would be the stupidest thing in the world to retile, only to find out that it all needs to come down. Here are photos - as you can see, there’s a 2X3 in front of the stud, so that would need to be cut, to push the whole thing back. Also, someone installed this slightly crooked. This is why I don’t want the co-op involved. Their people make a mess of things. 



Can a plumber gain access to the piping from behind the shower?

Being in a co-op makes life a bit more difficult.  I in my own home would just notch the 2x4 to push the valve back.  Being in a co-op/multi person building, I would not even think of touching structural members(2x4s/2x6s studs), by myself.

I can’t access the shower from the other side because there’s another building’s wall there... made out of concrete blocks. The 2X3 that the valve is sitting in front of is not structural. There is a whole set of studs behind it... plus this side wall isn’t load bearing. I can notch it myself but I have almost no knowledge of plumbing so I’m wondering how the plumbing would be pushed back. Can it be done in a tight space after I close it up or does a plumber need access to the whole wall/pipes?

Could you simply notch the studs, push back the pipes into the notch (strap if necessary) and repair the studs with a stud shoe?  (Add some blocking against the back wall if necessary.)  Does the tub spout suffer a similar issue?
